# Sharepoint 2010 Workflow error: Access Denied

Tags: sharepoint-designer-workflow

When I Publish or Save a new Sharepoint 2010 Workflow. It's warning me:

> Server Error: Access Denied

The Sharepoint 2013 Workflow work fine.
I'm an administrator account of my tenant and I have full control on this site.
[image]

How can I fix this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for SharePoint Online, you need to run the following:

```
Connect-SPOService https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com
Set-SPOSite https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $false
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you, @Trevor. Can you explain to me what happens with this script?